# why can't edit in buffer after save in file?

Tags: occur

In file I disable Read-only mode (by `C-x C-q`):
[image]

But if I want to edit buffer I get message:

```
Text is read- only
```

[image]

Comment: The `*occur*` buffer is only a list of lines matching the pattern you searched for. Why do you want to edit that? If you *do* want to edit the text, perhaps in order to do something useful with it, just copy it into a new buffer. Then you can edit to your heart's content. … Oh wait, I missed some important information from the *title* of your question. It appears you have saved the occur buffer into a file, and wish to edit it? Then perhaps changing away from `occur` mode by running `M-x normal-mode RET` will do the trick.

Comment: But I can't delete first line. M-x normal-mode - not help for first line.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Can you tell us step by step what you've done and what you want to happen? Saving the results of `M-x occur` creates a plain text file. You should be able to edit that file normally when you re-open it, and it should not be in `occur-mode` when you do. Something else is going on here I think.

Comment: It looks like you still have `occur-mode` on. But your mode-line format looks strange for me. So I am not sure about that.

Comment: Maybe the particular text you're trying to edit has a read-only property? That overrides read-only for the buffer as a whole.

Comment: Indeed, the first line has the text property `read-only` turned on, as you can see if you place the cursor on the line and run `M-x describe-text-properties RET`. You can remove them by selecting all the text, then going to the Edit menu and selecting `Text Properties` → `Remove Text Properties`. That runs `facemenu-remove-all`, which you can also run with `M-a facemenu-remove-all RET`.

Comment: @Drew The headline in occur buffers has the read-only text property put on it. That is true. But I've tried it: If you copy the buffer text and paste it to another buffer the read-only text property goes away. (Maybe it is filtered out.) But in the case of the OP the error message "Text is read-only" supports your assumption. What does [Occur] in the modeline say? Looks like the buffer is in Occur mode. In that case the buffer would be read-only.

Comment: If the buffer is not read-only but there are text snippets with the read-only text property put on them you can remove that property with `M-: (let ((inhibit-read-only t)) (remove-text-properties (point-min) (point-max) '(read-only nil)))`.

Comment: @Tobias (In response to the message two above this one) Yes, but the OP tried to deal with that by running `C-x C-q`, which then turned out not to be sufficient. No wonder; in addition to the first line having the `read-only?  text property, in Occur mode you are also hampered by the keymap. It's *way* easier to just copy the entier text to a new buffer and edit it.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Ah, the OP did not copy paste the text from the occur buffer but he saved the Occur buffer directly to a file. Hm, okay one shouldn't do that. Even `M-x normal-mode` does not clear the text properties. Your `facemenu-remove-all` is still needed.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion above (sixth comment, five comments above this one unless someone removes their commend)? What happened when you did?

Comment: Yes, sorry. "facemenu-remove-all" - this help. Thanks

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Please, write your suggestion about `facemenu-remove-all` as an answer. @Alexei: Please accept HaraldHance-Olsen's answer to mark this question as done.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Why when I save *occur* buffer to separate file not whole lines are editable?

Comment: @Tobias Done. Took me a while; I've been extremely busy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `*Occur*` buffer will be in a major mode unsurprisingly called `occur-mode`.
This mode, or perhaps the code that prepares it, or a combination of the two,
do a number of things, including these:

- the buffer is marked read-only
- it gets its own keymap, with most keys marked undefined
- the first line is given some text properties

The best way to deal with the first two items is to get the buffer out of Occur mode and into some other mode: Perhaps text mode or fundamental mode will do: Just type `M-x text-mode RET` or `M-x fundamental-mode RET` (you don't have to type it all, thanks to tab completion). Or you can use `M-x normal-mode` and let emacs pick the mode based on the ending of the file name (and possibly the contents, but probably not in this case).

You now have a reasonable keymap, and the buffer is not readonly.

To get rid of the text properties in the first line,
mark the first line, or the entire buffer if you wish
(`C-x h` is handy for this),
then go to the Edit menu and select
Text Properties ▶ Remove Text Properties.

Note that the way to *discover* the existing properties is Edit ▶ Text Properties ▶ Describe Properties.
If you do that, after first placing the cursor in the first line of the `*Occur*` buffer, you will see this:

```
There are text properties here:
  face                 underline
  occur-title          #<buffer tt.txt>
  read-only            t
```

That last one, `read-only t`, is your culprit.