# Why I can't delete first line after save *occur* buffer to separate file?

Tags: text-editing, occur

Windows 10, Emacs 26.1

I have file - `file_first.txt`:

[image]

I want to find all line content word **hello**. So I use `occur` for this

[image]
Nice.

Now I want to save result to SEPARATE file: `file_second.txt`

To do this I use menu `File->Save As (C-x C-w)`

[image]

And success save content of *occur* buffer to file `file_second.txt`

[image]

Nice.

Now I want to delete first line

```
2 matches for "hello"...
```

in file `file_second.txt`
[image]

To do this I go to first line, select whole line and press any key.

[image]

But I get message:

```
Text is read only
```

And first line NOT DELETE.

Why? This is not any more `*occur*` buffer. It's a SEPARATE file.

But I can success delete another line (e.g. second line)

Why I can edit any lines EXCEPT FIRST LINE?
[image]

Comment: You already asked [essentially the same question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/46904) and got some pointers there.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen but it not help

Comment: The the right thing to do is to ask for clarification on that other question, or possibly updating it to making it clearer. (That will also bump it to the front page.) Certainly, without feedback indicating *why* it did not help, I am unable to help further.

Comment: "facemenu-remove-all" - this help.

Comment: Why when I save *occur* buffer to separate file not whole lines are editable?